# React: unnecessary component update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are 3 react components, two of them inside of the first. The first component contains some state which used only in third component. When I update state from third component with callback react additionally update second component. But second component have no changes.

Why does this happen and how to avoid it?

here is my code:

```
var app = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'app',

    settingsChanged: function (value) {
        console.log('app.settingsChanged');
        this.setState({ settings: { value: value } });
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return { settings: { value: 1 } }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null,
                React.createElement(component1),
                React.createElement(component2, { settings: this.state.settings, settingsChanged: this.settingsChanged })
            )
        );
    }
})

var component1 = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'component1',

    render: function () {
        console.log('component1.render');
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null, 'component1')
        );
    }
})

var component2 = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'component2',

    tbValueChanged: function(e) {
        this.props.settingsChanged(e.target.value);
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log('component2.render');
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null,
                React.createElement('div', null, 'component2'),
                React.createElement('input', { value: this.props.settings.value, onChange: this.tbValueChanged })
            )
        );
    }
})
```

In the console I see this:

```
component1.render app.js:27
component2.render app.js:42
app.settingsChanged app.js:5
component1.render app.js:27
component2.render app.js:42
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67m0z3ts/1/

Comment: In component2, why  React.createElement('input', { value: this.props.settings.value, onChange: this.tbValueChanged }), although no settings for this component ???

Comment: for component2 settings was set but not for the component1. I can not understand why they are both updated, but should only be a second

Comment: can u please put it in jsfiddle or plnkr ?

Comment: I updated the post, the results in the console browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what's happening is a normal behaviour, once there is something changed in the main component, all components in that main one will be rendered again.

BUT the good news that you can change this default behaviour using `shouldComponentUpdate()`, which is true by default. Look at [react.js documentation in advanced performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html).

I hope that helps.

Good Luck

Comment: And what about virtual dom and change only that what has changed?

Comment: It's doing it! React will can your render method whenever your state changes (by default), but will apply to DOM only the diff between the previous DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent React rendering with method ***[shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html)***.
So you have to add a these lines of code to your component1:

```
    getInitialState : function(){
        return {
            shouldUpdate: true
        }
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
        return nextState === this.state.shouldUpdate
    },
```

And also ***[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/67m0z3ts/2/)***

I hope it will help you!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to get into detail here, but in addition to other replies, you can try to enable the [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) from React. From the docs:

> Under the hood, the mixin implements `shouldComponentUpdate`, in which it compares the current props and state with the next ones and returns `false` if the equalities pass.